# What do I need to do to satisfy my Area 51 commitment?

Tags: discussion, support

I've asked 10 (IMO good quality) questions on this SE, and I'm yet to fulfill my commitment.

What do I need to do to fulfill it?

Comment: To what "commitment" are you referring to? And what would you expect to see happen that would signal to you that "your commitment has been fulfilled"?

Comment: area 51 commmitment. I should get a badge saying I've fulfilled it.

Comment: Can you provide a link where this badge is mentioned?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos - Ok, I can't see anything about badges - but if you look at my Area 51 profile, you can see that I have a fulfilled commitement for the beer beta. Am wondering how I achieve it for the economics one. http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/99212/dwjohnston?tab=stats

Comment: Admittedly the Are 51 FAQ is vague : "_Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions..._". I don't believe there is a badge for fulfilling a commitment, but indeed, the criterion should be more clear. I added the "support" tag in your question so that somebody from the SE team may answer your question.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Is this question answerable in some way?

Answer (score 2):

In general, commitments and badges take a day or two to be allocated: there are timed processes on the server that run at quieter times to do these jobs. So you should see your area51 account updated within a day or two, having fulfilled the commitment.

That's different to elevated privileges: you get more privileges on the site once your reputation passes certain thresholds: and those privileges are active as soon as your rep passes the threshold, without delay.